# Iterating a given sequence

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I need to loop through the numbers from 1 to 96, skipping some values:

```
2, 4, 5, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 18, 20, ..., 81, 83, 86, 88, 89, 91, 94, 96
```

I've tried various loops but they all completely fail, and while I'd put up my attempts they honestly don't feel worth looking at from my point of view.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Due to complaints and confusions they entire pattern should be 
2,4,5,7,10,12,13,15,
17,19,22,24,25,27,30,32,
34,36,37,39,42,44,45,47,
49,51,54,56,57,59,62,64,
66,68,69,71,74,76,77,79,
81,83,86,88,89,91,94,96.

Thanks again! :)

Comment: didnt get ur question ?

Comment: Ok, so two even, two odds, two even etc?

Comment: "I need to loop through the numbers 1>96" - Please don't use greater-than symbol to say "up to" on a programming site ;)

Comment: [Read this.](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Write down the steps on paper, think though it, write down the results of each step. Code a simple example of your steps. Use the debugger to work though each step. Compare that to your written notes. If it differes on a step, thats a bug to fix.

Comment: I dont think the people that have answered this so fa can see the pattern as they all give the wrong sequence. The pattern doesn't reset every 16!

Comment: Do you understand that it's your task to supply the pattern, darn it? Why do you think that SO users should waste their time to help you if you yourself don't want to be helped?

Comment: I thought I has supplied enough of the pattern for it to be seen. I did say I found it hard to explain. Some people like you, give this sight a bad name by making people asking questions not want to ask.

Comment: @Spitfire2k6 If no one can figure out what your asking you need to edit the question into a form that *can* be easily understood. Please read https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx and http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

This works (even if it's not the most beautifull code i've ever written) :

```
    var even = true;
    var cpt = 0;
    var s = '';
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= 96){
        if (even){
            if (i%2 == 0){
                s += i + ',';
                cpt++;
            }
            if (cpt == 2){
                even = !even;
                cpt = 0;
            }
        }else{//odd             
            if (i%2 == 1){
                s += i + ',';
                cpt++;
            }
            if (cpt == 2){
                even = !even;
                cpt = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    alert(s);
```

return :

```
2,4,5,7,10,12,13,15,18,20,21,23,26,28,29,31,34,36,37,39,42,44,45,47,50,52,53,55,58,60,61,63,66,68,69,71,74,76,77,79,82,84,85,87,90,92,93,95,
```

It's not exactly the same result or the end but the behavior at the begining is respected

Comment: Wow, there's a lot of code for the task THAT simple. )

Comment: Yes like i said. But it's maybe easier to anderstand how it works with a detailed program than thanks to a 'magic' formula or code line.

Comment: No, you should just simplify the algorithm. ) Instead of trying to check whether the number is even or odd at each step, see that there's a sequence of pairs of numbers, and distances between those are either 1 or 3. )

Comment: Yes you are right. We also can saw that it's 2+2+1+2+3+2+1+2+3+2+1+2+3+2+1+2+3+... and create the string with it. But it's quite magic you don't think so?

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```
for (var i = 2; i < 96; i++) {
  console.log(i);
  console.log(i+=2);
  i & 1  &&  (i+=2);
}
```

... but that'll finish with `93, 95` because you actually didn't check how that sequence should end. Hint: it's not `94, 96`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1; i < 49; i++)
  console.log(2 * i - Math.floor((i - 1) % 4 / 2));
```

This displays 2 * i, minus zero or one in this sequence [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,...]